# Need to figure out why this external *.js function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have used code found on the website provided by my tutor and even had him have a look at it and still, we have no clue what it doesnt work. I used simpler 2 lines of code to output date/time since, but I would love to understand this and make this work. Help would be appreciated - also first time user, so if something is not as it should be, im sorry

HTML code

```
<p id="Date">Date and time will show here</p>
```

JS code

```
function dateAndTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDay();
    var daylist = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday                         ", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    console.log("Today is : " + daylist[day] + ".");
    var hour = today.getHours();
    var minute = today.getMinutes();
    var second = today.getSeconds();
    console.log("Current Time : " + hour + " : " + minute + " : " + second);
    //  var date = new Date();
    document.getElementById("Date").innerHTML = dateAndTime.toString();
}
```

I am supposed to get date and time on the screen, however I get nothing, it doesnt even seem to run.

Comment: You never call the function

Comment: The value of `daylist[3]` indicates that in your actual code you've splitted a string into two lines, or is it just in the post? Any error messages in the console?

Comment: Tried calling it as per Vikash Singh example but still doesnt work.

Comment: the string is not split into two lines, its just like that in the post for some reason

Comment: NEW USER, obviously a newbie getting downvotted for asking a question cheers community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gregory Sky   Kindly use this code.
Put Java Script code in bottom of all code.

You have access element in java script.

```
<body>
<span id="Date"></span>

</body>
<script>
dateAndTime(); 
function dateAndTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDay();
    var daylist = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    console.log("Today is : " + daylist[day] + ".");
    var hour = today.getHours();
    var minute = today.getMinutes();
    var second = today.getSeconds();
var dateTime=  "Current Day:"+daylist[day]  + " <br>    Current Date And Time :"+hour + " : " + minute + " : " + second;
    //  var date = new Date();
    document.getElementById("Date").innerHTML = dateTime;
}
</script>
```

Comment: wow ok this one works. Could you epxlain why yours code works and mine doesnt? I can seee differences, but dont understand why it is happening, as the code I have been using is from another webstie and it is supposed to work. Also if ou could include example of how to use this code when inserted into js file that would be much appreaciated.

Comment: This code works, because JavaScript function should be call after html element initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Like others are saying you aren't running the function so it is just sitting there being pretty. (A refactor would help that function being prettier btw)

Every function is nothing more then a piece of code waiting for you to call it.

Check this jsBin I haven't changed it but one it runs it works.
https://jsbin.com/nimubiqoma/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
dateAndTime()
```

Answer (score -1):

First issue is that you are not calling the function anywhere, so below i used self invoking function, and second issue is that you are assigning function definition to innerHTML, instead you should like below:

```js
(function dateAndTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDay();
    var daylist = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    console.log("Today is : " + daylist[day] + ".");
    var hour = today.getHours();
    var minute = today.getMinutes();
    var second = today.getSeconds();
    console.log("Current Time : " + hour + " : " + minute + " : " + second);
    //  var date = new Date();
    document.getElementById("Date").innerHTML = "Current Time : " + hour + " : " + minute + " : " + second;
})()
```

```html
<p id="Date">Date and time will show here</p>
```

Comment: did you included JS file path in your html file ? like this 
  <body>
    <p id="Date">Date and time will show here</p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

Comment: I did and there was no joy. thank you for your help. Code from the next person worked so I am sticking with it.